# Project two or more columns with Prometheus metrics into one field and add characters between the values

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have 3 metrics generated by sql_exporter that are showing corresponding SQL instance uptime part:

- `mssql_server_uptime_days` - >=0
- `mssql_server_uptime_hours` - >=0 <24
- `mssql_server_uptime_minutes` - >=0 <60

I'd like to show total uptime of instance in Grafana. Preferably in format `dd hh:mm`.

I tried to concatenate them with the transformation Concatenate fields with no success.

Could it be done using Prometheus as data source?

P.S. I now that I can query DBMS to get this result easily. But I'd like not to, to keep single data source for this dashboard: Prometheus.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert you metrics into value in seconds:

```
mssql_server_uptime_days * 24 * 60 * 60 +
 mssql_server_uptime_hours * 60 * 60 +
  mssql_server_uptime_minutes * 60
```

And set units of column (Standard options > Unit) to Time > `duration (d hh:mm:ss)`

Comment: Thank you for the response, your code solve my problem!
I had to include some parenthesis and also I added seconds.

(mssql_server_uptime_days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) 
+ 
( 
  (mssql_server_uptime_hours * 60 * 60) 
  + 
  (
    (mssql_server_uptime_minutes * 60)
    +
    (mssql_server_uptime_seconds)
  )
)